# Why is this "next" arrow rendering slightly below the height of the "previous" arrow?

Tags: jquery, css

My main issue and question is mostly a CSS issue. I have an html-template driven calendar using CLNDR.js and the "next month" arrow is lower than the "prev month", no matter what I do, I can't fix this through CSS.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y072a94e/

The relevant portion of the css, I *believe* is

```
#full-clndr .clndr-controls .clndr-previous-button {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

#full-clndr .clndr-controls .clndr-next-button {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;  
}
```

But to me, this is how I would do it, and its not working, so it must be something else?

If anyone has good amount of experience with CLNDR.js, the whole thing just seems to be totally askew, as far as styling. Is this something that must be dealt with through css? Or am I missing something in clndr's configuration?

Comment: No, it's being rendered on the next line. Try putting your right arrow element before the title element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this by changing the order of the elements

Change:

```
<div class="clndr-previous-button">&lsaquo;</div>
<div class="month"><%= month %></div>
<div class="clndr-next-button">&rsaquo;</div>
```

to:

```
<div class="clndr-next-button">&rsaquo;</div>
<div class="clndr-previous-button">&lsaquo;</div>
<div class="month"><%= month %></div>
```

The order of your floated elements matters. By having the floated elements first, you allow the content that follows to float up and occupy the space between them.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/y072a94e/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

The month name is filling the available width, pushing it to the next line. The easiest solution is just to move the "next" arrow before the month name in your HTML:

```
    <div class="clndr-controls">
      <div class="clndr-previous-button">&lsaquo;</div>
      <div class="clndr-next-button">&rsaquo;</div>
      <div class="month"><%= month %></div>
    </div>
```

---

If that's not an option, you could instead change the `.month` element to `inline-block` so it doesn't take up the full width:

```
#full-clndr .clndr-controls .month {
    display: inline-block;
}
```